# Moment js converts date to US timezone while formatting

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using Moment js to format date. I calcuate the current date using javascripts default utility `new Date()` and pass it to moment for formatting.

To my sheer disbelief, I get the time in the required format but in US timezone.

Here is my code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate)
console.log(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

Output;

```
Tue Oct 15 2019 09:24:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2019-10-14 23:24
```

I tried logging `moment(new Date()).utcOffset()` and was shocked to see -240. My system is in IST. The date and time on system are on IST. Even consoling new Date shows I am in IST then where is moment getting `UTC-4` then? I tried running `tzutil /g` on cmd and it printed IST.
What exactly is going behind the scenes?

Comment: check this URL https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @Vishal Are you this on your machine or server?

Comment: @VishalGulati Moment.js chooses system/server timezone as a default timezone. Check for your default timezone.

Comment: @SanketPhansekar My remote machine is set to IST, and the system time shown is also correct. Then how and from where is moment pickingUTC-4 when I am running at UTC+5:30?

Comment: Try printing moment(currentDate).format() and see the output.

Comment: @SanketPhanseka I tried logging moment().utcOffset() and was shocked to see -240. My system is in IST. The date and time on system are on IST. Where is moment getting UTC-4 then? any idea? I tried running tzutil /g on cmd and it printed IST.

Comment: Where does your code execute, in browser or on server? Check the timezone of the same environment.

Comment: @31piy Its a Vue app that runs on browser, the app is deployed on AWS and runs on browser.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. `utcOffset()` correctly prints 330 for me in the Indian Standard timezone, when the code is executed on browser.

Comment: I have shared the code above, the new date shows IST but utcOffset with moment prints -240. @31piy

Comment: moment.js has no idea what the system offset is, it gets it from `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` and deduces the IANA representative location based on the offset at different times of year caused by daylight saving (or lack of such changes). If you're getting something different, it's because the system that moment.js is running on is set to that timezone.

Comment: I find it extra strange because `new Date()` does appear to get the right timezone. I find it hard to believe that `new Date()` uses a different mechanism than moment. @VishalGulati is your code sample a _full_ codesample, or is it possible that somewhere `moment.tz.setDefault` is called?